# How do I return the number value of an if statement if certain conditions are met?

Tags: javascript, return-value

I am working on a function where if certain properties of an array are true then return the number of those conditions that are true.

e.g.

```
if (a > b || a < c || d == e || f == e)
{
  return "number of condition that are met";
}
```

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* attempt to solve this yourself?

Answer (score 3):

Store the conditions in an array

```
const conditions = [
   (a,b,c,d,e,f) => a>b,
   (a,b,c,d,e,f) => a<c,
   (a,b,c,d,e,f) => d==e,
   (a,b,c,d,e,f) => f==e,
];
```

Now, you can use `filter` to find how many are true

```
const howManyTrues = conditions.filter(cond => cond(a,b,c,d,e,f) )
if(howManyTrue > 0){
    return howManyTrue;
}
```